# How to remove Bookmarks have other details

Tags: bookmarks

How to remove the bookmarks other details ?

```
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
    {\fontfamily{phv}}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\filleft #1}
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{1cm}

    \chapter{\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\fbox{\parbox[l][8pt][c] 
    {\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\textbf{Chapter 1 Operation Overview}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: well the easiest is not to put them into the chapter argument. If you want to change the formatting of the chapter title, redefine \chapter in a suitable way, check the titlesec documentation.

Comment: section commands like `\chapter{` should only have text not formatting, the format of the headings is part of the document setup, not specified in each heading